# Forms authentication table locations

Tags: asp.net, forms, forms-authentication

When using aspnet_regsql to create the base tables for forms authentication, is it recommended that these tables be stored inside of the application database catalog or should a database catalog just for authentication be created.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify what jro said you can join across dbs but you'll lose some performance there.

Secondly if you want to maintain referential constraints you'll need the tables in the same DB.  What I mean is if you have a new table for your app, say CustomerOrders, and you want to ensure the UserID column values exist in the Users table you'll need those in the same DB.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter.

If you need to eventually join records on the membership tables with your own catalog, I would suggest using an application database.

Otherwise, use your preferences for database management.